# Категории товаров лучший алгоритм

Tags: postgresql, golang

Вопрос очень глобального характера!

Суть: Нужно придумать алгоритм и хранение в базе данных списка категорий,  каждый товар может находится в разных категориях , но есть основная главная  например товар Холодильник - категория ЭЛЕКТРОНИКА ,но  он также находится в категории товары для дома. Непонятно как все это в базе хранить и выводить список категорий. Пока заспопорился на данном этапе .

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    cat_id integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    cat_name CHAR(24) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    active boolean NULL DEFAULT true,
    cat_description CHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Тоесть есть категоирия родитель и ее предки! но как товары в разные подкатегории добавить и вывести все это потом, товаров порядка 40 млн

Пишу на Go lang

Comment: Отдельная таблица с двумя полями id-категории и id-товара который к ней относится

Comment: это самый простой вариант! а если хранить все в 1 тестовом поле аля 1,45,53,63,31,87 и потом выборки делать через LIKE ... Вопрос в лучшем алгоритме по скорости

Comment: Это не самый простой, а единственно верный для реляционной БД вариант. Если на таблице будет индекс по id-категории (ну или это поле будет первым в первичном ключе) то поиск по этому индексу будет очень быстрым. А like из середины поля со списком никакой индексации не поддается и дает гарантированный перебор всей таблицы

Comment: Единственный минус отдельной таблицы - если вы хотите показать на экране сразу миллион товаров и указать все их категории. Но пользователю одновременно миллионы записей не показывают, а по паре десятков отображаемых записей получить все категории не очень долго.

Comment: чтож! спасибо  буду двигаться дальше